# How to make WSS4J load the keystore password from a callback?

Tags: java, cxf, ws-security, wss4j

I'm using Apache CXF to build a Web Service. It uses Apache WSS4J to provide WS-Security functionality. I need to make a SOAP request and it must be signed.

This is the content of the properties file I pass to WSS4J:

```
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.provider = org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type = PKCS12
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.provider = BC
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password = 12345678
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.alias = my-alias
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.file = my_certificate.p12
```

I want to get rid of that line with my password wrote as plain text. I removed that line and provided a password callback handler to my WSS4JOutInterceptor, like in the code above:

```
public SoapInterceptor newSignerInterceptor() {
    Map<String, Object> outProps = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION, "Signature");
    outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.USER, config.getKeyAlias());
    outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIG_KEY_ID, "DirectReference");
    outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.USE_REQ_SIG_CERT, WSHandlerConstants.SIGNATURE_USER);
    outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.USE_SINGLE_CERTIFICATE, "false");
    outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PW_CALLBACK_CLASS, this.getClass().getName());
    outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIG_PROP_FILE, config.getPropertiesFileName());
    return new WSS4JOutInterceptor(outProps);

}

@Override
public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) throws IOException, UnsupportedCallbackException {
    for (int i = 0; i < callbacks.length; i++) {
        if (callbacks[i] instanceof WSPasswordCallback) {
            ((WSPasswordCallback) callbacks[i]).setPassword(password);
        }
    }
}
```

But that didn't work. It doesn't find the password in the properties file and uses a default password, "security".

How to make it use a callback to get the password?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can implement a [CallbackHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/security/auth/callback/CallbackHandler.html):

```
public class PasswordCallbackHandler implements CallbackHandler {

    @Override
    public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) throws IOException, UnsupportedCallbackException {
        for(Callback callBack:callbacks){
            if(callBack instanceof WSPasswordCallback){
                ((WSPasswordCallback)callBack).setPassword("password");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then add the handler to the properties:

```
outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PW_CALLBACK_CLASS, PasswordCallbackHandler.class);
```

you can also use PW_CALLBACK_REF to set a reference of the handler.

Answer (score 0):

Merlin doesn't invoke the callback for Keystore password, so the password always has to be in the property file. Fortunately it can be encrypted.

The solution is described nicely here:
[Encrypting passwords in Crypto property files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31023223/encrypting-passwords-in-crypto-property-files)

Copied solution from the link above:

1. Download the jasypt-1.9.2-dist.zip
2. Get a Encoded password with this command `encrypt input=real_keystore_password password=master_password algorithm=PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES`
3. Copy the OUTPUT (EXample: 0laAaRahTQJzlsDu771tYi)
4. As you're using this algorithm, you need the Java Cryptography
   Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength. Put in your JDK.
5. Put the encoded output in the properties

   ```
   org.apache.wss4j.crypto.provider=org.apache.wss4j.common.crypto.Merlin

   org.apache.wss4j.crypto.merlin.keystore.type=jks 
   org.apache.wss4j.crypto.merlin.keystore.password=ENC(0laAaRahTQJzlsDu771tYi)

   org.apache.wss4j.crypto.merlin.keystore.alias=my_alias 
   org.apache.wss4j.crypto.merlin.keystore.file=/etc/cert/my_keystore.jks
   ```
6. In the CallbackHandler, put the master_password wich you used to
   generated the encoded one:

   ```
   public class WsPasswordHandler implements CallbackHandler {
   @Override
   public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) throws IOException, UnsupportedCallbackException {

       for (Callback callback: callbacks){
           WSPasswordCallback pwdCallback= (WSPasswordCallback) callback;
           final int usage =pwdCallback.getUsage();
           if (usage == WSPasswordCallback.SIGNATURE || usage==WSPasswordCallback.DECRYPT) {
           pwdCallback.setPassword("parKeyPassword");
       }
       if (usage==WSPasswordCallback.PASSWORD_ENCRYPTOR_PASSWORD){
           pwdCallback.setPassword("master_password");
       }
       }           
   }
   ```

   }