# Encrypting passwords in Crypto property files

Tags: java, encryption, cxf

**Problem**

I'm using Apache CXF 3.0.7, and read that, in the [new features](http://ws.apache.org/wss4j/migration/newfeatures20.html) you have the ability to store a (BASE-64 encoded) encrypted version of the keystore password in the Crypto properties file, but I don't know how to add it, I didn't find an example of this implementation.

In the apache web says:

> A typical example of the contents of a Crypto properties file (for
>   Signature creation) is as follows:

```
 org.apache.wss4j.crypto.provider=org.apache.wss4j.common.crypto.Merlin
 org.apache.wss4j.crypto.merlin.keystore.type=jks
 org.apache.wss4j.crypto.merlin.keystore.password=security
 org.apache.wss4j.crypto.merlin.keystore.alias=wss40
 org.apache.wss4j.crypto.merlin.keystore.file=keys/wss40.jks
```

> Note that the password used to load the keystore is in cleartext. One of the new
>   features of Apache WSS4J 2.0.0 is the ability to instead store a
>   (BASE-64 encoded) encrypted version of the keystore password in the
>   Crypto properties file. A new PasswordEncryptor interface is defined
>   to allow for the encryption/decryption of passwords. A default
>   implementation is now provided based on Jasypt called
>   JasyptPasswordEncryptor, which uses "PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES".
>
> The WSPasswordCallback class has an additional "usage" called
>   WSPasswordCallback.PASSWORD_ENCRYPTOR_PASSWORD, which is used to
>   return the master password for use with the PasswordEncryptor
>   implementation. When WSS4J is loading a Crypto implementation via a
>   properties file, and it encounters a password encrypted in the format
>   "ENC(encoded encrypted password)", it queries a CallbackHandler for a
>   password via this WSPasswordCallback usage tag. It is possible to pass
>   a custom PasswordEncryptor implementation to WSS4J via the new
>   configuration tag ConfigurationConstants.PASSWORD_ENCRYPTOR_INSTANCE
>   ("passwordEncryptorInstance").
>
> It is possible to pass a custom PasswordEncryptor implementation to
>   WSS4J via the new configuration tag
>   ConfigurationConstants.PASSWORD_ENCRYPTOR_INSTANCE
>   ("passwordEncryptorInstance").

I guess I have to declare in my properties file something like that:

```
org.apache.wss4j.crypto.merlin.keystore.password=ENC(?????)
```

But I don't know how to encrypt my password with the default JasyptPasswordEncryptor implemented. 
Also, I guessthat in my CallbackHandler I'll have something like that:

```
if (usage==WSPasswordCallback.PASSWORD_ENCRYPTOR_PASSWORD){
                ????
    }
```

**Solution**

Ok, with the test running, I test my solution and now is working.

1. Download the [jasypt-1.9.2-dist.zip](http://www.jasypt.org/download.html)
2. Get a Encoded password with this command
   encrypt input=real_keystore_password password=master_password algorithm=PBEWithMD5AndTripeDES
3. Copy the OUTPUT (EXample: 0laAaRahTQJzlsDu771tYi)
4. As you're using this algorithm, you need the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength. Put in your JDK.
5. Put the encoded output in the properties

   org.apache.wss4j.crypto.provider=org.apache.wss4j.common.crypto.Merlin
   org.apache.wss4j.crypto.merlin.keystore.type=jks
   org.apache.wss4j.crypto.merlin.keystore.password=ENC(0laAaRahTQJzlsDu771tYi)
   org.apache.wss4j.crypto.merlin.keystore.alias=my_alias
   org.apache.wss4j.crypto.merlin.keystore.file=/etc/cert/my_keystore.jks
6. In the CallbackHandler, put the master_password wich you used to generated the encoded one:

   public class WsPasswordHandler implements CallbackHandler {

   ```
   @Override
   public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) throws IOException,
           UnsupportedCallbackException {
       for (Callback callback: callbacks){
           WSPasswordCallback pwdCallback= (WSPasswordCallback) callback;
           final int usage =pwdCallback.getUsage();
           if (usage==WSPasswordCallback.SIGNATURE||usage==WSPasswordCallback.DECRYPT){
               pwdCallback.setPassword("parKeyPassword");
           }
           if (usage==WSPasswordCallback.PASSWORD_ENCRYPTOR_PASSWORD){
               pwdCallback.setPassword("master_password");
           }
       }           
   }
   ```

   }

And this is it... Now I've to figure out how to get this working in a external local.property, with Spring, and so on.. but this is another history.. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This test should help you: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/webservices/wss4j/trunk/ws-security-dom/src/test/java/org/apache/wss4j/dom/message/PasswordEncryptorTest.java

You can get the encrypted password by instantiating the JasyptPasswordEncryptor with the master password, as in the test, and encrypt the keystore password. Then copy this into your crypto properties are per:

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/webservices/wss4j/trunk/ws-security-dom/src/test/resources/crypto_enc.properties

Colm.

Comment: Thank you for the test.. Its working now, I have my password wrong when I tried the Jasypt command line! ;)