# Apache WSS4J - How to load a key store password from database

Tags: cxf, keystore, public-key-encryption, ws-security, wss4j

In order to provide key store information we have store-password in plain text file. To secure the key store either we need to encrypt the store password or move them in db. Is there any way to access this key store information from Database during run time. I tried below ref for encrypting password in crypto.properties but that is not helping.

[Encrypting passwords in Crypto property files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31023223/encrypting-passwords-in-crypto-property-files)

Answer (score 0):

There is no support there by default, you would have to write your own implementation of PasswordEncryptor instead to communicate with the DB:

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/webservices/wss4j/trunk/ws-security-common/src/main/java/org/apache/wss4j/common/crypto/PasswordEncryptor.java